# Paginate Rows into Columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I 'paginate' every X row into a new column?

```
ORIGINAL LIST
Col A
-----
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Is there a way to break after every third item? Turning the list into this:

```
PAGINATED LIST
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
-----   -----   -----   -----    
1       4       7       10
2       5       8
3       6       9
```

Comment: Actually, I only need this for the printed result.

Comment: This is a good question, so why the downvotes? It is a good habit to explain when downvoting. So come on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

In the example below, I placed the transformed range beside the original list (A1:A15).

In **B1**, enter this formula, and then copy it down and across:

```
=INDEX(original,((COLUMNS($B:B)-1)*3)+ROW(),1)
```

Where
`original` refers to A1:15

[image]

Just do a quick copy-paste-values move and then delete the original column. You could use another sheet for this.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using your formula in a separate sheet, starting in column B. I then changed the hard-coded *3 into *COUNTIF(A$1:A$2000, ">0") to have it handle dynamic number of rows.

Comment: Glad to help. Welcome to SuperUSer!