# Excel Single column into rows, VBA script insight

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

Okay, so much similiar to the below link but mine is a bit different.
[Paginate Rows into Columns in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/432392/paginate-rows-into-columns-in-excel)

I have a lot of data in column A, I want to take every 14 to 15 rows and make them a new row with multiple columns. I'm trying to get it into a format where SQL can intake the data. I figured the best way was to get them into rows then make a CSV with the data.

So it would like like below: (wow, the format totally didn't stick when posting)

```
column A     column B     C     D     etc

1               1         2     3      x
2               16        17    a      b
3
x
y
z
15
16
17
a
b
c
```

I can clarify if needed, but I'm stumped on how to get the data out of the single column with so many rows in the column.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want 15 per line, and the data starts in A1:
in B1, put this formula `=OFFSET($A$1,((ROW()-1)*15)+MOD(COLUMN()-2,15),0)` and copy it to C1:P1, then copy that down as far as you need to
The end of the data will be signified by rows of zeros