# Split N*Y rows of data into Y columns of N rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My question is basically the same as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/432392/paginate-rows-into-columns-in-excel), but the answer given for that question [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukCj1.jpg) when I try it (see image), and I don't understand the syntax of the function well enough to troubleshoot the problem.

Ultimately, I'd like to make a more advanced version, likely using a script/VBA/macro that can convert the table on the left to one on the right for each different drug concentration, all of which would have concentrations, timepoints, and values in the same columns just rows farther down the sheet. [example sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zuoc1.jpg)

For now I'd settle for just being able to separate the N*Y rows of values into Y columns of N rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you add one column of data to identify the Replicate value, you can build a pivot table with a few clicks.

[image: Pivot table]

This pivot table can be created by dragging the fields into the areas as seen here:
[image: Pivot pane]

Comment: That works very well. I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a sounding board to remove the thinking block. Glad I could help.